# Athena inset into new value error : extraneous input 'INSERT' expecting {'(', ',', 'SELECT', 'VALUES', 'TABLE'}

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

user_db schema is like this:

```
  2020-03  11         80     121
  2020-04  20         30     121
  2020-05  13         99     121
  2020-06  12         19     121
......
```

old  user db is like :

```
month,user_count, total, grand_total, percentage_old, total_percentage_old
....
2020-06    20       30      121       73.3%           18.1%
```

Need update the value percentage,total_percentage  from and older data db record  percentage_old, total_percentage_old from June in  an Athena query,

```
with user_db as (
select *, user_count/total*100 as percentage, user_count/grand_total*100 as total_percentage
)

INSERT INTO  user_db (percentage,total_percentage) 
select percentage_old, total_percentage_old
from old_user_db  as u
where u.month = '2020-06'
```

but got this error:

> extraneous input 'INSERT' expecting {'(', ',', 'SELECT', 'VALUES',
> 'TABLE'}

Need to keep with clause for re-use in the other query.
Expect to get user_db table with June percentage and total_percentage using older user db value.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Athena doesn't support adding fields to existing rows. `INSERT INTO` will always add a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the cause of the error, since the error is a syntax error, but you're trying to insert into the CTE, which is not going to work anyway.

`WITH user_db (…)` defines a temporary relation `user_db` that only exists during the query execution. If you have a table called `user_db` already it's going to be shadowed by this relation. `INSERT INTO user_db` cannot insert into this relation because it really doesn't exist as such.

The `user_db` relation also doesn't have a `FROM` clause, which is not supported, Athena won't know where the `user_count`, `total`, and `grand_total` columns come from.

I don't know if it is possible to write insert statements like this in other databases, I've never seen it. Either way it is not supported in Athena. Look at the [`INSERT INTO`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html) documentation if you want to know more about what is supported.

I suspect you are trying to do something like this, but I'm not entirely sure:

```
INSERT INTO user_db (month, user_count, percentage, total_percentage) 
SELECT
  month,
  user_count,
  user_count/total * 100,
  user_count/grand_total * 100
FROM old_user_db
WHERE month = '2020-06'
```

You will have to provide more information if you want more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

try to move "INSERT INTO  user_db (percentage,total_percentage) " to the first line

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment or upvote yet by @jztest is right. My suspicion is that the temporary table doesn't exist once the insert function is called. It needs to be nested within it for the temporary table to exist for the select query